# How/Why callback url is used with respect to API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, shared-libraries, callbackurl

I am using HelloSign api for c# and on hellosign API page they are asking me to add callback url and they will test it. I am not sure what is call back url and where and how to use it. Can any one please explain me what is call back and why its useful or how to use? 
Or can you explain call back url in simple language?

Answer (score 0):

in simple team, If you have made nay request that result will be posted to griven url (call back url) where api will make request and you will get result from api.

A callback URL will be invoked by the API method you're calling after it's done. So if you call

```
POST /api.example.com/foo?callbackURL=http://my.server.com/bar
```

Then when /foo is finished, it sends a request to http://my.server.com/bar. The contents and method of that request are going to vary - check the documentation for the API you're accessing.

Comment: is used for getting access token from api and passing that to my methods or classes for verification purpose >??? So by using request i can access that .. Right ???

Comment: What I have mention is in regard of general behaviour of different api. Not sure about the one is mention by you.

Comment: @user3788832 was it helpful or u still have confusion ?